# Dynamically adding properties to an ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, expandoobject

I would like to dynamically add properties to a ExpandoObject at runtime. So for example to add a string property call NewProp I would like to write something like

```
var x = new ExpandoObject();
x.AddProperty("NewProp", System.String);
```

Is this easily possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a property of a C# 4 dynamic object when you have the name in another variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033410/how-to-set-a-property-of-a-c-sharp-4-dynamic-object-when-you-have-the-name-in-an)

Answer (score 613, accepted):

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.NewProp = string.Empty;
```

Alternatively:

```
var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
x.Add("NewProp", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I've never realized that Expando *implements* IDictionary<string, object>. I've always thought that cast would copy it to a dictionary. However, your post made me understand that if you change the Dictionary, you also change the underlying ExpandoObject! Thanks a lot

Comment: It is amazing, and I have demonstrate that they are actually becoming properties of the object with sample code in my post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888144/name-variable-using-string-net/11893463#11893463, thanks

Comment: getting `Error 53 Cannot convert type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion`

Comment: It's `IDictionary<string, object>`, not `IDictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to cast to dictionary and add properties. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783541/expandoobjects-leak-memory-when-used-as-an-idictionary-string-object-to-add-new-properties

Comment: @Marko: That "leak" is only if you add many different property names, and would have the same exact behavior if you added the same property names via `dynamic`.

Comment: May worth pointing out the first one doesn't work with `var x`. It only works with `dynamic x`.

Comment: It's important to note that when you're casting as `IDictionary` that you don't use `dynamic` as the variable type.

Comment: If you implement as an IDictionary, then you don't have to cast it to use the methods from either the parent or derived class:
`IDictionary<string, object> myExpando = new ExpandoObject();`

Comment: Nullability required in my case: `IDictionary<string, object?> dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();`

Answer (score 33):

As explained here by Filip - http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/10/02/adding-properties-and-methods-to-an-expandoobject-dynamicly/

You can add a method too at runtime.

```
var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
x.Add("Shout", new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hellooo!!!"); }));
x.Shout();
```

Comment: Your code is plain wrong, you skipped the most important part, which is the cast to a Dictionary.

Comment: @tocqueville, this answer is an enhancement to the current question and does not directly answer the question. The answer is an additional possibility. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a sample helper class which converts an Object and returns an Expando with all public properties of the given object.

```
public static class dynamicHelper
    {
        public static ExpandoObject convertToExpando(object obj)
        {
            //Get Properties Using Reflections
            BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
            PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(flags);

            //Add Them to a new Expando
            ExpandoObject expando = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                AddProperty(expando, property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));
            }

            return expando;
        }

        public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            //Take use of the IDictionary implementation
            var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;
            if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
            else
                expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
//Create Dynamic Object
dynamic expandoObj= dynamicHelper.convertToExpando(myObject);
    
//Add Custom Properties
dynamicHelper.AddProperty(expandoObj, "dynamicKey", "Some Value");
```

Comment: "var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary;" this line need to change to "var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;"

Comment: To make it even more awesome use those as extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best solution I've found. But be careful with that. Use exception handling because it might not work on all of the cases

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
}
```

//another nice extension method you might want to use

```
    public static T JsonClone<T>(this T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", nameof(source));
        }

        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
    }
```

Comment: Might not be as elegant as IDictionary, but only working solution if you later use this variable as dynamic (eg dynamic.Properties())

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I've found. But be careful with that. Use exception handling because it might not work on all of the cases

```
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
    }
```