# remove null column from collection in c#

Tags: c#, linq, collections, expandoobject

I have a table Menu and the data is like the attached screen shot
[Database table](http://s2.postimg.org/x67jdi0op/table.png)

and I want output like below image,

[image: http://s16.postimg.org/6evrtzkwl/output.png]

Means all the null values or integer ==0 should be hidden.

Right now I am showing these 5 columns only as you can see in 2nd screen shot..

I have something like this..

```
List<Menu> lstMenus = obj.GetMenus(10);
```

My code is

```
var menus = new List< dynamic >();

foreach (Menu menuBE in lstMenus)
    {

        dynamic menu = new
        {

            menuBE.MenuID,
            menuBE.ParentMenuID,
            menuBE.LinkText,
            menuBE.ScreenName,
            menuBE.Parameters,
            menuBE.URL
            // if(menuBE.Parameters.Length>0 ){ Parameters = menuBE.Parameters,}
        };
        menus.Add(menu);
    }
```

and I want to put some condition like the last commented line in foreach loop. If `menuBE.Parameters.Length>0` then this Parameters column should add be in **dynamic menu** else not.
Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: Have you tried left joining on the same table to remove null entries

Comment: @liquidsnake786 : can you please suggest how? data coming in my lstMenus is correct. So I have to make change in while add to 
**var menus**

Comment: What exactly does showing the Params do? Is it something that can be controller by a visible property? Maybe show the menuBE and menu classes to give a better understanding

Comment: @James : menus will used to return the json response. So I only want those columns in json response which have values. and MenuBE is the replica of this http://s2.postimg.org/x67jdi0op/table.png

see the image for better understanding..

Comment: If the parameter is for the QueryString, will there likely be more than 1 parameter in the QueryString at any one time? I am thinking a coalesce is probably all you need.

Comment: @James : I am using this code in WEBAPI and returning json response from the API. So I only want those fields in response which dont have NULL or Blank values. I have nothing to do with the QueryString.
The answer from **André Figueiredo** solves my problem but only for tables, In which I  have to check 1 or 2 columns. In some tables I have to 15-20 columns, in that case It will not help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood, in the opposite of James & techloverr, you want to keep records with parameter null:

```
foreach (Menu menuBE in lstMenus){
    if (menuBE.Parameters.Length > 0){
       dynamic menu = new{
           menuBE.MenuID,
           menuBE.ParentMenuID,
           menuBE.LinkText,
           menuBE.ScreenName,
           menuBE.Parameters,
           menuBE.URL
       };
    }
    else {
       dynamic menu = new{
           menuBE.MenuID,
           menuBE.ParentMenuID,
           menuBE.LinkText,
           menuBE.ScreenName,
           menuBE.URL
       };
    }
    menus.Add(menu);
}
```

** **UPDATE** **

As I understand in the whole question, you **do not** want a property `Parameters` when source data have Parameters.Lenght == 0, and that's why you are using dynamic type.

It's **different** from "that's OK have a property 'Parameters = null'". If that's the approach, you don't need to use dynamic type. Just add items as list-item of a declarated strong-type variable or list-item of anonymous type.

With the `dynamic` type you add properties at declaration time. So, you have to separate the different assigns as the code above.
If you want to put `if` outside to avoid duplicate code, you use ExpandoObject:

```
var m = new List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>();
foreach (string item in new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }) {
    dynamic menuItem = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

    menuItem.pos1 = item;
    menuItem.pos2 = (item == "b" ? item : null); // wrong

    if (item == "c") {           // correct
        menuItem.pos3 = "I am at third iteration";
    }

    m.Add(menuItem);
}
```

See, if you put a breakpoint at `m.Add(menuItem);` these are the results:
**case item == "a":**

```
menuItem.pos1 = "a";
menuItem.pos2 = null; // wrong: pos2 must not exists
```

**case item == "b":**

```
menuItem.pos1 = "b";
menuItem.pos2 = "b";
```

**case item == "c":**

```
menuItem.pos1 = "c";
menuItem.pos2 = null; // wrong: pos2 must not exists
menuItem.pos3 = "I am at third iteration"; // correct: pos3 only exists here.
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I may have misinterpreted looking back on it. Not much I can do to enhance what this answer gives really so just leaving mine as is :)

Comment: @andre this is the lowest quality coding I have seen

Comment: yes I need somthing like this but I have to check around 15-20 column so in that case will have to put many if conditions..
can't i add if condition inside this code  ..

dynamic menu = new{
           menuBE.MenuID,
           menuBE.ParentMenuID,
           menuBE.LinkText,
           menuBE.ScreenName,
           menuBE.Parameters,
           menuBE.URL
       };

Comment: @vishwarajmalik you can use above answer

Comment: Yes this will work but I have to check in around 15 columns so will have to put 15 if else if blocks.. and for first if there will be 15 conditions in a single If.

I don't want to follow that approach..

Comment: Sure, you can (and should) refactor this code. You can put it in a helper function or use ExpandoObject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938397/dynamically-adding-properties-to-an-expandoobject

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo : Yes I think this will solve my problem. Let me check with this code and thn I will get back to you..

Thankyou all for your replies..  :)

Comment: It is working with foreach loop.. 
Can I use this `ExpandoObject` in a select statement like below..
`countriesBE.Select(countryBE => new {  \\ my condition here  });`

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code snippet

```
  foreach (Menu menuBE in lstMenus)
    {

        dynamic menu = new
        {

          MenuID = menuBE.MenuID,
          ParentMenuID =  menuBE.ParentMenuID,
          LinkText =  menuBE.LinkText,
          ScreenName = menuBE.ScreenName,

          URL = menuBE.URL,
            Parameters = (menuBE.Parameters.Length>0) ? menuBE.Parameters : null
        };
        menus.Add(menu);
    }
```

Comment: **Error** : Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: @vishwarajmalik  now try

Comment: @vishwarajmalik I have changed the answer

Comment: Now this will add in list..
{ MenuID = 9, ParentMenuID = , LinkText = My Agenda, ScreenName = MyAgenda, URL = testurl9, **Parameters** =  }
**Parameters** is still coming. I dont want this column to show if Parameters is NULL or Empty.

Comment: @vishwarajmalik is it?

Comment: yes it will not effect the code but I don't want those columns which has NULL or blank value. I am converting this response to json and column without values will make the json heavy.

Comment: then remove :null from that line

Comment: "Means all the null values or integer ==0 should be hidden.". with this code, when menuBE.Parameters.Length == 0 there will a property "Parameters: null"  and not the absence of property Parameters.